# RecyclerView: add item at position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I get data from a server that I want to display in a `RecyclerView`. Firstly I get a list that contains an URL where data should be retrieved as well as the position this data should be put inside the `RecyclerView`. 
I want to show the data as soon as I retrieve it, and not wait for all data to be retrieved. 
So for example if theres a list-item that says "url: www.url.com/data.php, postition: 3", I want to retrieve this data from the server and fill the third row of my `RecyclerView` with this data. Even if there's no first and second element yet.

Right now I do it like this: As soon as I now how many positions I have to retrieve, I create an `Adapter` that contains `numSections` elements that are all null. Like so:

```
ArrayList<ContentPreviewSectionModel> emptySections = new ArrayList<>();
while(emptySections.size() < numSections) emptySections.add(null);
RecyclerView contentPreviewList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.content_preview_list);
contentPreviewListAdapter = new RecyclerViewDataAdapter(this, this, emptySections);
contentPreviewList.setAdapter(contentPreviewListAdapter);
```

When I retrieved the content of one URL, I update the RecyclerView like so:

```
    @Override
    public void setSectionContentRetrieved(int position, ContentPreviewSectionModel content,) {
        contentPreviewListAdapter.addItemAtPosition(content, position);
        contentPreviewListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

`addItemAtPosition` is simply a `arrayList.set(position, content)` on the Adapters data structure.

I was wondering if this is the easiest way to achieve what I want? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, probably it's the most easy way of doing this

Comment: also use `new ArrayList<>(Collections.<ContentPreviewSectionModel>nCopies(numSections, null)` instead of while cycle

Answer (score 4):

**Instead** of using `contentPreviewListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

you should use:
`contentPreviewListAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);`

(When you want to add item at desired position)

And use:
`contentPreviewListAdapter.notifyItemInserted(emptySections.size() - 1);`

(When you want to add item at the end)

Note: 
    Do this after calling `addItemAtPosition()` and don't call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `yourAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position)` where `position` is where you need to insert item in recyclerview.